# Fetch person name - Node JS

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have an excercise where i need to compare fetches done sequential and parallel.

First i have made a fetch function that looks like this:

```
const URL = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";
 
function fetchPerson(url) {
    fetch(url)
    .then (data => data.json()) 
    .then (data => {
       console.log(data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error)
    })
}
```

The output from this looks like this:

[image]

This works as it should, (the console log is just for test) it prints the whole object out, however i only want the names of the people.

So i have a function called printNames looking like this:

```
async function printNames() {
  try {
    console.log("Before");
    const person1 = await fetchPerson(URL + "1");
    const person2 = await fetchPerson(URL + "2");
    console.log(person1.name);
    console.log(person2.name);
    console.log("After all");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

However the output of this is "name is undefined", can anyone explain what i have done wrong here?

I should end up having a fetch method that of course doesnt print the whole response out, and only the printNames method prints the names of the two people.

Hope i explained it to be understandable, im quite new in JS and trying to learn.

Comment: Which content you receive from your fetch? Is it `person1` and object or an array? I guess it is an array, so you will be able to loop it, and get 'name', something like: `const names = person1.map(d => d.name)`

Comment: you need console it your person1 and person2 response

Comment: You need to change your function so that you return a Promise that resolves to your desired value: `return fetch(url).then(data => data.json())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return a promise from `fetchPerson`:

```
function fetchPerson(url) {
    return fetch(url)
    .then (data => data.json());
}
```

Otherwise these lines

```
const person1 = await fetchPerson(URL + "1");
const person2 = await fetchPerson(URL + "2");
```

make no sense

Comment: Keeping the logs in fetchPerson() will result in `person1` and `person2` being undefined

Answer (score 0):

Just call your function with the id appended to the URL.

In your second code version, the api calls are asynchronous so they take some time to complete but the lines `console.log(person1.name)` and `console.log(person2.name)` being synchronous run before that call has been completed. You can attach a `.then` method to that api call to avoid that.

```js
const URL = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";
 
function fetchPerson(url) {
    fetch(url)
    .then (data => data.json()) 
    .then (data => {
       console.log(data.name)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error)
    })
}

fetchPerson(URL+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen by your logs and your code, the following:

```
fetch(url)
    .then (data => data.json())
```

returns a Promise, which resolves with your data object once it fulfils. In order to get `printNames` to work, you need to return this Promise from your `fetchPerson()` function, otherwise, you will be using `await` on `undefined`, which doesn't achieve do much.

Once you return your promise:

```
function fetchPerson(url) {
    return fetch(url)
    .then (data => data.json()) 
}
```

you will be able to `await` it in your `printNames()` to obtain the resolved value.

See working example below:

```js
const URL = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";
function fetchPerson(url) {
  return fetch(url).then (data => data.json());
}

async function printNames() {
  try {
    console.log("Before");
    const person1 = await fetchPerson(URL + "1");
    const person2 = await fetchPerson(URL + "2");
    console.log(person1.name);
    console.log(person2.name);
    console.log("After all");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

printNames();
```